# Azure AD B2C : Log out of social account (Azure AD using OIDC)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an application that uses B2C to have users sign in by either using a local account or by using a Azure AD account.
During Logout, the local session is cleared completely, however the AD session persists.

I understand this is by design on B2C, where it does not completely clear social accounts.

However, given a fresh browser (all cookies and cache cleared) if I log in to my b2c application using Azure AD account and then try to log out. Should it still not clear the session completely?
Given I have not signed in any other AD application.

This seems like a security risk if a user uses AD account to log in on a public computer.
What can be done to sign out the AD user completely? I am ok with other social sessions ending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed with Microsoft that it was not possible to clear login session completely for external AD login from b2c app. That is because the AD login (social) creates a persistent cookie under login.microsoftonline.com domain on the browser. This cookie cannot be cleared by b2c as its under different domain.

To clear the persistent cookie, you must call the logout endpoint for login.microsoftonline.com : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout

In b2c app, the logout method looked like :

```
 public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            MsalAppBuilder.ClearUserTokenCache();
            IEnumerable<AuthenticationDescription> authTypes = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes();
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(authTypes.Select(t => t.AuthenticationType).ToArray());
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes();
        }
        HttpContext.Response.Redirect("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout");
    
    }
```

This cleared out the b2c session cookie as well as the AD login cookie, thus properly ending the session